# How to show All names in order from Employee table and make one of the names shows up first

Tags: sql, oracle

We have an `Ename` column in the `employee` table containing the following names:

```
ENAME
-----
Laith
indi
Cup
Odai
```

How can I show the all the names from the employee table in alphabetical order but make `Odai` show at the top of the list? Like this:

```
ENAME
-----
Odai
Cup
indi
Laith
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Name
From Employees
Order By Case When Name = 'Odai' Then ' ' Else Name End
```

If you want multiple names to be treated this way you can have an OrderBy Table with Name and SortName and join it to Employees and order by OrderBy.SortName

Comment: What if there is already a row with just a space character in it?

Comment: Thank you , but can you explain what you did ?

Comment: The case syntax can be in the select list or in the group by and order by.  I chose to use a blank space as working with name and addresses by profession I like to see numbers and nulls rise to the top so they can be dealt with.  However you didnt ask for that and so the answer from jva might suit you better.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name
FROM employees
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'Odai' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, name
```